# Validate 2 values to determine "Yes" or "No"

Tags: php, mysql, database

What is the best way to figure out if a vehicle may me driven or not.

Lets say we have different Driving License types:
A, B, BE (Etc.)

I have the following tables...

```
Person         ( ID, Name, LicenseTypes )
DrivingLicense ( ID, Type, ExpDate )
LicenseTypes   ( ID, Type )
Vehicle        ( ID, Brand, VehicleType )
VehicleType    ( ID, VehicleType )
```

I want to accomplish, if a Person has Licensetype "A" and the Vehicle he owns is a car, he MAY NOT drive the vehicle, because this Vehicle requires "B".

If the person has multi driving license types, lets say: A and B, where the requirement for the car is B, he MAY drive the vehicle.

Is it best to add a column to the Vehicletype table, with Licensetype and Join these tables?

Or can i use a MySQL line/PHP command to compare these values and use some kind of statement? IF value = "" and "", but i think that will be a messy solution.

Comment: Does each license allow you to drive one vehicle type only, or can a license allow you to drive multiple vehicle types? Can each vehicle type only have a single license type applicable to it? This will determine if you want a 1:1, 1:N or N:N relationship between them.

Comment: "what is the best way to figure out what is the best way to find out"? lovely meta question. I'm pretty sure it's off-topic here....

Comment: A license type allows me to drive more than 1 vehicle type, lets say I've got license type: B, then I'm allowed to drive a car, and a scooter. 1 vehicle type kan have multiple license types which allows the person to drive the vehicle. So i would say, a N:N relationship.@Karoly, Thank you for noticing, i have edited my post.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data FROM EACH TABLE so we can better see the situation you are trying to process.  More importantly, the person table has the LicenseTypes column.  Is this a comma delimited list, if so, this is not a good design plan, but should be a separate table of PersonLicenseTypes where it has the person ID AND the corresponding license type to allow multiple entries per person to simplify joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is going to be long. I hope you get the general gist of what I tried here; all in all I used 6 tables. Also I didn't use your table names (there were some edits in the question and in comments while I was trying out my stuff), sorry 'bout that.

The below code works with e.g. `sqlite3` and I think I used just ANSI SQL so it should work with everything. Use your local db's particularities to improve; e.g., I didn't put in auto-increment ID's and only use `varchar` for text as this is the biggest common denominator.

Below each table definition I put in a few dummy dataload statements to see whether everything works, and I put in a few `select` statements to make a nice listing. When you run this in `sqlite3` then you get the following output:

```
What person has which license?  
Karel        A             required to drive a motorcycle
Karel        B             required to drive a car       
John         AM            required to drive a scooter   
John         B             required to drive a car       

What vehicle types may be driven with which licenses?  
car                B           
scooter            AM          
scooter            A           
scooter            B           
motorcycle         A           

Which person may drive which vehicle given their license?  
Karel        Solex         scooter            A             required to drive a motorcycle
Karel        Vespa         scooter            A             required to drive a motorcycle
Karel        BMW K1200GT   motorcycle         A             required to drive a motorcycle
Karel        Ducati Monst  motorcycle         A             required to drive a motorcycle
Karel        Peugeot 307   car                B             required to drive a car       
Karel        Volvo V70     car                B             required to drive a car       
Karel        Solex         scooter            B             required to drive a car       
Karel        Vespa         scooter            B             required to drive a car       
John         Solex         scooter            AM            required to drive a scooter   
John         Vespa         scooter            AM            required to drive a scooter   
John         Peugeot 307   car                B             required to drive a car       
John         Volvo V70     car                B             required to drive a car       
John         Solex         scooter            B             required to drive a car       
John         Vespa         scooter            B             required to drive a car
```

Onward into the SQL code. First off, you have persons and licenses that they hold. I modelled this using a typical cross table; `person` has information on persons, `license` on licence types, and `person_license` is the cross table that says which person has which licenses:

```
-- Known persons
create table person (
    person_id   integer not null unique primary key,
    person_name varchar(255) not null
);
insert into person (person_id, person_name) values (1, 'Karel');
insert into person (person_id, person_name) values (2, 'John');

-- Known license types
create table license (
    license_id   integer not null unique primary key,
    license_name varchar(3) not null unique,
    license_desc varchar(255)
);
insert into license (license_id, license_name, license_desc)
values (1, 'AM', 'required to drive a scooter');
insert into license (license_id, license_name, license_desc)
values (2, 'A' , 'required to drive a motorcycle');
insert into license (license_id, license_name, license_desc)
values (3, 'B' , 'required to drive a car');

-- What licenses do the persons hold (cross table so that 1 person may hold
-- multiple licenses. For example: Karel has A and B, John has AM and B.
-- NOTE: There is no expiry date here, you could stick it into this table when
-- you need it.
create table person_license (
    person_id  integer references person(person_id) not null,
    license_id integer references license(license_id) not null
);
insert into person_license (person_id, license_id) values (1, 2);
insert into person_license (person_id, license_id) values (1, 3);
insert into person_license (person_id, license_id) values (2, 1);
insert into person_license (person_id, license_id) values (2, 3);

-- Here is a listing to show what licenses a given person has.
select 'What person has which license?';
select person.person_name, license.license_name, license.license_desc
  from person, license, person_license
 where person_license.person_id = person.person_id
   and person_license.license_id = license.license_id;
select '';
```

Next up are the vehicles and vehicle types in the system. For the demo I've put in three types; scooters, motorbikes and regular cars. You might want to change this into cars-without-trailer and cars-with-trailer and so on, depending on the license types you need to support. Table `vehicle_type` is of course the type, and `vehicle` is the table of all vehicles in the system. It has a 1:N relationship, so per vehicle it lists the type.

```
-- Vehicle types.
create table vehicle_type (
    vehicle_type_id   integer not null unique primary key,
    vehicle_type_name varchar(255) not null    
);
insert into vehicle_type (vehicle_type_id, vehicle_type_name)
values (1, 'car');
insert into vehicle_type (vehicle_type_id, vehicle_type_name)
values (2, 'scooter');
insert into vehicle_type (vehicle_type_id, vehicle_type_name)
values (3, 'motorcycle');

-- Known vehicles in our system (2 cars, 2 scooters, 2 motorbikes)
create table vehicle (
    vehicle_id      integer not null unique primary key,
    vehicle_name    varchar(255) not null,
    vehicle_type_id integer not null references vehicle_type(vehicle_type_id));
insert into vehicle (vehicle_id, vehicle_name, vehicle_type_id)
values (1, 'Peugeot 307', 1); 
insert into vehicle (vehicle_id, vehicle_name, vehicle_type_id)
values (2, 'Volvo V70', 1); 
insert into vehicle (vehicle_id, vehicle_name, vehicle_type_id)
values (3, 'Vespa', 2); 
insert into vehicle (vehicle_id, vehicle_name, vehicle_type_id)
values (4, 'Solex', 2); 
insert into vehicle (vehicle_id, vehicle_name, vehicle_type_id)
values (5, 'BMW K1200GT', 3); 
insert into vehicle (vehicle_id, vehicle_name, vehicle_type_id)
values (6, 'Ducati Monster', 3);
```

Then comes the relationship between a vehicle type and the required license. I made this as an N:N relationship so that one license allows you to drive more than one vehicle type. In this demo, a car license allows you to drive a car or a scooter; a motorbike license allows you to drive a motorcycle or a scooter, and a scooter license only allows you to drive a scooter but nothing else.

```
-- What license do you need for what type of a vehicle?
-- A scooter license allows you only to drive a scooter.
-- A motorcycle license allows you to drive a motorbike and a scooter.
-- A car license allows you to drive a car and a scooter.
create table vehicle_type_license (
    vehicle_type_id integer not null references vehicle_type(vehicle_type_id),
    license_id      integer not null references license(license_id)
);
-- Car requires B
insert into vehicle_type_license (vehicle_type_id, license_id) values (1, 3);
-- Scoorter requires AM, A or B
insert into vehicle_type_license (vehicle_type_id, license_id) values (2, 1);
insert into vehicle_type_license (vehicle_type_id, license_id) values (2, 2);
insert into vehicle_type_license (vehicle_type_id, license_id) values (2, 3);
-- Motorcycle requires A
insert into vehicle_type_license (vehicle_type_id, license_id) values (3, 2);
-- And a listing to show it
select 'What vehicle types may be driven with which licenses?';
select vehicle_type.vehicle_type_name, license.license_name
  from vehicle_type, license, vehicle_type_license
 where vehicle_type.vehicle_type_id = vehicle_type_license.vehicle_type_id
   and license.license_id = vehicle_type_license.license_id;
select '';
```

And finally.. here's the result of who may drive what vehicle:

```
-- Finally...
-- Let us see what vehicles the persons may drive.
select 'Which person may drive which vehicle given their license?';
select person.person_name, vehicle.vehicle_name,
       vehicle_type.vehicle_type_name,
       license.license_name, license.license_desc
  from person, vehicle, vehicle_type,
       license, person_license, vehicle_type_license
 where vehicle.vehicle_type_id = vehicle_type.vehicle_type_id
   and license.license_id = person_license.license_id
   and person.person_id = person_license.person_id
   and vehicle_type_license.vehicle_type_id = vehicle_type.vehicle_type_id
   and vehicle_type_license.license_id = person_license.license_id
;
```

Comment: Thank, this has really cleared up my view on the situation! Thank you for the great effort you made on the answer, i will definitly go through your post once again, but i think i can really work with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are going to get where you want to with the structure you are starting with. I think if you write it out in natural language, you might have a better view:

- I am a Person.
- A Person has a Driving License.
- A Driving License has one or more License Types
- A License Type refers to one or more Vehicle Types
- A Vehicle Type refers to one or more Vehicles, but each Vehicle can only be one VehicleType

So I would go with the following tables:

```
***Person***        ***DrivingLicense***  ***DrivingLicenseLicenseTypes***
ID                  ID                    ID
Name                ExpiryDate            DrivingLicense_ID
                    Person_ID             LicenseType_ID

***LicenseTypes***  ***LicenseTypeVehicleTypes*** ***VehicleTypes***    ***Vehicles***
ID                  ID                            ID                    ID
LicenseType         LicenseType_ID                VehicleType           Make
                    VehicleType_ID                                      Model
                                                                        VehicleType_ID
```

Now I can have a motorbike, which is VehicleType A, and a Driving License, which is LicenseType B, but which will allow me to drive both VehicleType A and B, so I know I am licensed to drive my motorbike.

ETA: Ah, you're right, I needed another link table between LicenseTypes and VehicleTypes, LTVT. Now you can have multiple vehicle types on a single license type. So you can have a LicenseType B1 (car+trailer), which covers VehicleType B and B1 (car AND car and trailer). Does that answer where you are going?

Edit2:

Lets stick some sample data in here.

```
Person: (1, 'goodevans'), (2, 'John');
DrivingLicense: (1, '2015-01-01', 1), (2, '2015-10-01', 2);
VehicleTypes: (1, 'Car'), (2, 'Motorbike');
LicenseTypes: (1, 'Car'), (2, 'Motorbike');
Vehicles: (1, 'Ford', 'Focus', 1), (2, 'Chevrolet', 'Caprice', 1), (3, 'Ducati', 'Multistrada', 2);
LicenseTypeVehicleTypes: (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2);
DrivingLicenseLicenseTypes: (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2);
```

Ok, given the data above:

- The first two rows of LTVT show that LicenceType 1 (Car) is applicable to VehicleType 1 (Car) and 2 (Bike)
- The 3rd row of LVTV shows that LicenseType 2 (bike) is applicable only to VehicleType 2 (bike)
- The 1st row of DLLT shows that my license, ID 1, is a Car type.
- The 2nd row of DLLT shows that your license, ID 2, is a Motorbike type.
- I have a Car type license, valid until Jan next year, which allows me to drive both Cars and
  Motorbikes.
- You have a Motorbike license, valid until Oct next year, which only allows you to ride Motorbikes.

Does that clear it up?

Comment: Allright, i see what you are doing there. So actually in the table: LicenseTypes, i get different rows like: Row 1, Licensetype: A, VehicleType_ID 1 (Which is car). Row 2, Licensetype: B, VehicleType_ID 1 (Which is motor). And in my DLLT table, i can get duplicate DrivingLicense_ID but have different LicenseType_ID's. I think i get the point.. This is a good solution. So if i search up a person, i can echo all the cars that person owns, but how can i "compare" the license type and the vehicle type, to validate the person can drive this vehicle, i'm not sure about this part.

Comment: I'm not totally sure how to fill in my data right now.. In the new table: LTVT i can have the following data: ID, LicenseType_ID, where only ID is Unique. Does that mean i have to adjust my DLLT table, and change LicenseType_ID to LTVT_ID? But how can i link mulitple VehicleTypes on 1 LicenseType then? Do i insert Data like: ID=1, LicenseType_ID=1, VehicleType_ID=B, B1 or do i add different rows? But when i do that, i can't link to 1 LicenseType? Or do i add multiple rows in my DLLT table, where DrivingLicense_ID is unique, en there will be duplicatie entries for LicenseType_ID?

Comment: Let me rephrase my last commen/questiont: I'm filling in all my LicenseTypes in the table: LicenseTypes. In the table: DLLT, do i need to add multiple rows with a Unique ID, duplicate DrivingLicense_ID, and a unique LicenseType_ID for each DrivingLicense_ID? Ofcourse a different DrivingLicense_ID can use the same LicenseType_ID. And where do i JOIN the LTVT table?

Comment: That does clear it up! Thank you very much.. My next challenge is trying to join these tables.. Using INNER JOINS for all tables won't, i'm getting errors on that. So I'm going to try figure that out..